# SSH agent forwarding mixed with su user -

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, openssh, ssh-keys

If I ssh to my server as such:

```
ssh root@<ip> -A
```

Then I do this remotely:

```
ssh git@github.com
# Hi username! You've successfully authenticated
```

Then this remotely:

```
su user -
```

Then this remotely:

```
ssh git@github.com
# Permission denied (publickey).
```

How do I get this to work without SSH'ing to the user directly (because I need to easily switch back and forth often)

Thanks

Comment: Please edit question and indicate if you do `su user -` on the local or on the remote machine. If you do it on the local machine, you need proper keys to authenticate yourself on github both in `~root/.ssh/` and `~user/.ssh/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as expected. What is happening is that when you `ssh -A` the certificates already loaded in your SSH agent are made available in the user session that you open on the server. When you then change the user to somebody else using `su` that privilege is for security-related reasons not given to the target user. What you typically want to do instead is to

1. `ssh -A user@ip` or
2. put the private key on the server, SSH into it and load the key there using `eval "$(ssh-agent)" && ssh-add`.